# Test Method else/if not returning expected value

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, react-props

Trying to test the following method below. Test is only returning 'column' at the moment. Just wondering how could I test the others such as 'polar', ' columnstacked' etc..

```
   getChartType = () => {
if (this.props.defaultData.stacked === 'polar') {
  return 'polar'
}
else {
  if(this.props.defaultData.stacked === 'false'){
    return this.props.defaultData.type
  }
  else{
    if(this.props.defaultData.stacked === 'true' && this.props.defaultData.type === 'column'){
      return 'columnstacked'
    }
  else if(this.props.defaultData.stacked === 'true' && this.props.defaultData.type === 'bar'){
      return 'barstacked'
    }
  }
 return 'column'
```

Using Jest and Enzyme for React Js. 
Shallow to render my component
Here is what my test looks like at the moment.

```
 it('Test getChartType method',() => {
  wrapper.setProps({
  defaultData:{
    stacked:"",
    type:"",
    category:{
        $:{
            id:{},
        },
    },
}})
wrapper.update();
expect(wrapper.instance().getChartType({defaultData:{stacked:""}})).toEqual("column"); //WORKING
expect(wrapper.instance().getChartType({defaultData:{stacked:"percent", type:'area'}})).toEqual("areastacked100");  //NOT WORKING
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue here is the `getChartType` function.

In the test, the code sends objects as arguments (`{defaultData:{stacked:""}}`), but the function `getChartType` does not accept any arguments; it reads its `props`.

This is why it's hard to test; in the isolation of the test, `props` are always the same. I would suggest converting `getChartType` to a function that accepts an object argument. In your code, you'll send `props` or part of `props`; in your test, you'll send your object.

The function will be easier to test and understand, because you aren't relying on something from outside the function (`props`).

Comment: I was able to test it by creating separate tests, and able to check if it was returning what I expected.